# Fill a ChoiceField in Django template with external data

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I'm new to Django and I'm having a hard time understanding **forms** when the data to choose from are not taken from the database nor user input that they're generated on the go.

I currently have a template with a single `ChoiceField`. **The data inside this field aren't fixed and they're calculated on the go once the page is requested.** To calculate it I need the username of the User who is logged in. Basically, the calculation returns a list of lists in the form of `((title, id),(title,id),(title,id))`, etc. that I need to put into the ChoiceField to make the User choose from one of the options.

Now, I'm not understanding how to pass the calculated list of lists to the form. I've tried to add the calculations inside the form as below but it is clearly the wrong way.

The main issue is that, to calculate my list of lists, I need the `request` value, and I don't know how to access it from the form.

Another idea was to add the `generate_selection` function inside the `init` but then I don't know how to pass `main_playlist` to being able to add it to `ChoiceField`

Below my not working `forms.py`

### forms.py

```
class ChoosePlaylistForm(forms.Form):

    playlists = forms.ChoiceField(choices=HERE_SHOULD_GO_main_playlist)

    def generate_selection(self):
        sp_auth, cache_handler = spotify_oauth2(self.request)
        spotify = spotipy.Spotify(oauth_manager=sp_auth)
        user_playlists = spotify.current_user_playlists(limit=10)

        main_playlist = []
        for playlists in user_playlists["items"]:
            playlists_list = []

            playlists_list.append(playlists['name'])
            playlists_list.append(playlists['id'])
            main_playlist.append(playlists_list)

        return main_playlist

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(ChoosePlaylistForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('playlists',)
```

The views should be something like below so I'm able to pass the request

### views.py

```
form = ChoosePlaylistForm(request=request)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe overriding the field choices in the form constructor would work:

```py
class ChoosePlaylistForm(forms.Form):
    playlists = forms.ChoiceField(choices=())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('playlists',)

    def __init__(self, *args, request=None, **kwargs):
        super(ChoosePlaylistForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.request = request
        self.fields['playlists'].choices = self.generate_selection()

    def generate_selection(self):
        sp_auth, cache_handler = spotify_oauth2(self.request)
        spotify = spotipy.Spotify(oauth_manager=sp_auth)
        user_playlists = spotify.current_user_playlists(limit=10)

        choices = []
        for playlist in user_playlists["items"]:
            playlist_choice = (playlist["name"], playlist["id"])
            choices.append(playlist_choice)

        return choices
```

Comment: Try: `self.Meta.fields['playlists'].choices` instead of `self.fields['playlists'].choices`

Comment: `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'` with the updated code

Comment: @BartoszStasiak got invalid syntax

Comment: Yea. Sorry. I'm typing on the phone :P Can you try now?

Comment: @SavvaSurenkov `self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)` before `super` it works

Comment: @NictheDEV updated with `request` put directly in the \__init_\_ parameters

Comment: @SavvaSurenkov works as well, thanks